# Calculate average percentage

Tags: mean, percentage

How do you correctly calculate the average percentage?

Working with this test subject group:

```
Customer    Screens Clicked %Clicked
A           100     50      0.5
B           125     16      0.128
C           100     73      0.73
D           150     24      0.16
Total       475     163     1.518
```

How should the average percentage be calculated ( we are gong o use it as a benchmark).
Average of column %Clicked = 0.3795
Total Screens/ Total Clicked = 0.343157895

Comment: Those aren't percents. They're proportions. More seriously, there is a choice here. If your focus is at customer scale, you leave the data as they come. If it's at total scale, you apply Total Clicked/Total Screens (not vice versa, surely). Note that 1.518 is meaningless.

Comment: to connect the two simply weight the "average of column" average by Number of Screens